# My edit was rejected, looking for feedback

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I was looking for a way to limit the number of sub-processes created with Bash. At the end, I found [a thread about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511884/how-to-limit-number-of-threads-used-in-a-function-in-bash). Sadly, I could not find it directly using a web search engine.

This is because the OP (mis)uses the word "thread":

- OP uses `comand &` to spawn several sub-processes (not threads).
- All the answers refer to sub-processes, as expected.
- There is an up-voted comment on the question suggesting the misuse of the word "thread" in this case.
- An edit [was made by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6511884/revisions) (and accepted) to remove the tag `multithreading`.

I decided to [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9710239) so that next time it is easier to find and less confusing. However, the change was rejected (3 against 1). All the rejections stated that:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

However, I do not see how it deviates from the original intent of the post.

I would like to know what you think. I really wish there was a way to discuss it with those who rejected it, but I guess that is not possible. Perhaps you can help me understanding what is wrong about my edit or if, however, the edit was right.

Comment: I fixed the question to use the wording "threads/sub-processes" instead of just "threads".

Comment: The edit reason was the cryptic *"Make this question correct and more SEO friendly"* and that does not clearly explain why the edit is a good edit. Generally an edit should be clearly valid without knowing much about the subject matter. The edit reason allow the editor to explain the edit.

Comment: As well as being more clear in the edit summary (as @AdrianHHH suggested) you could also refer to the comment (that already points out the incorrectly used term) in your edit summary.

Comment: One problem with removing the word "thread" from the question is that if this is a common misunderstanding then people searching for "spawning several threads (sic)" when they mean sub-processes won't find this question and will ask a new one.

Comment: The ironic thing is that *you* also mis-use the word. We do not have *threads* here on Stack Overflow, we have *questions*.

Comment: @bob: you'll never go to bed without learning something new!

Comment: On a related note, a mod should maybe look at the guy who approved this edit. Not that he was wrong in this case, but he's never rejected *anything*. I think he needs a break.

Comment: @bob: also, that leads to weird definitions, as in: *Electorate gold badge. Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override the rejection of a legitimate edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348219/how-to-override-the-rejection-of-a-legitimate-edit)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For better or worse, reviewers don't tend to do a lot of research when they approve/reject edits. I certainly wouldn't expect them to magically divine all the research you've done personally, or the experience you're bringing to the table with your edit. For an edit that's rather substantial like this, but appears valid, you should *explain* it in the edit reason (that's what the edit reason field is for!). Then, reviewers will have an idea as to your intent and be less inclined to write off the edit as misguided.

Comment: This reminds me of someone who complained on Reddit a long while ago that he stopped "contributing" to Stack Overflow (in that person's case, editing) because his edit was rejected. He found a bug in a post, which his edit fixed, but the reviewers didn't know that (I guess he didn't leave a clear edit message). His edit was eventually made by another redditor with sufficient privileges to not have to go through the review queue.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I will try to be more precise when explaining my edits.

Answer (score 30):

Comment you've added to the review - "Make this question correct and more SEO friendly" is not exactly useful. "Correct" does not mean much and changing "thread" to "process" for the sake of SEO definitely deserves rejection.

More specific comment like: "OP used 'thread' as synonym of 'sub-process' which not the case for 'bash'" would likely yield more positive reaction.

Comment: Indeed, it was not well explained. I must admit I felt lazy to write an explanation, as (for me) it was pretty clear. That is certainly a bad practice and I will try to avoid it in the future. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would be more inclined to argue that your edit might have been something to work out with the OP. Whether OP miss-used or misunderstood could have perhaps more clearly solved the needed change. Admittedly, OPs are not always responsive, but the end result could have both improved the questions and OPs understanding leading to an answer.

Comment: I added a comment as well, asking OP to change this by themselves and also asking them to accept an answer. It has been more than 4 years since they asked and there is no accepted answer (nor a comment explaining why the current answers are invalid for them).