# How to override the rejection of a legitimate edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

A user with rep < 2000 [corrected a bug in one of my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15903036). But for some strange reason, this [legitimate](https://secure.php.net/setlocale) edit was rejected by three reviewers.

Of course, I could fix the post myself. But I want the fix to be attributed to the user who applied it in the first place. Even if it just means two unicorn points and the good feeling to have made a contribution.

I guess it is not possible for me to overrule a rejection, even for my own posts. So is there anything a mod could do?

Comment: This is not currently possible, but we are working on a feature that will allow you to override the community decision.

Comment: I see. Can you at least send the original user a message to tell them to apply the fix again, so it can hopefully be accepted by more careful reviewers? I hate to see a rejection for a meaningful contribution by mindless robo-reviewers. Or should I just let it go and fix it myself?

Comment: We don't have a "send a message to a user" feature (well, there is one, but it is not intended for casual communications). I get that you want to do the OP right, but until the override feature is live (hopefully today or early next week), fixing it yourself is the only option (unless you are willing to wait a few days).

Comment: Ok, I fixed it myself now. The user has also answered the question with an own post, so I just left a comment below their post.

Comment: Another option would be to ping the editor on another post of theirs, coordinate for them to apply the edit again, and then once they apply the edit again you can insta-approve it.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340745/792066 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339101/792066 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290017/792066 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320516/792066 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316817/792066 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340660/792066 TL;dr: reviewers are brain dead (and some on meta like them like that).

Comment: @Oded: Nice one on that feature!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way for an author to accept/improve a suggested edit after it's been rejected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251337/is-there-a-way-for-an-author-to-accept-improve-a-suggested-edit-after-its-been)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since [this feature was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/213575) you (or a moderator) can override reviewers decision by simply going to the [review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15903036) and clicking "Approve", as long as you don't edit the post (as you did). The opposite is also possible. A review can only be overridden exactly once.

Comment: This feature needs more visibility (suggested the same thing to Shog on the MSO post).

Comment: Update: [Shog says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#comment957088_295028) that it's an obvious option for new edts. Wonderful!

Comment: Excellent! Had I known it was just about to be released, I would have waited to try it. :)

Comment: You got the duplicate backwards -- my question is not only older, it is broader (accept AND improve)

Comment: @BenVoigt "my question is not only older" are you really using that as argument? REALLY?

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, I am.  Because all other things being equal, the older question is used as a duplicate target, and the new one is closed.  I've closed questions in the reverse direction myself, but only when the older question is badly written and doesn't fully express the ideas, which I don't believe to be the case here (clearly I'm biased). Notably, where the answers are doesn't affect dupe closure direction, since a diamond moderator can merge them to the existing question -- and my question has more answers anyway which are still valid (since the new method doesn't work after edits).

Comment: @BenVoigt oh, I know what you are talking about, [this guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/) is absolutely hideous, he's closing [older FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157852/) and even [discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192205/) against the newer one which he answered! We should take our collective social justice pitchforks and makes things right, or.... we could just keep this one open so it gets screen time on the Community Bulletin and people see it, since it's something that we want to advertise.

Comment: Not sure how 2013 is older than 2012.  And even the reverse direction would hardly be equivalent to closing against a brand-new question that did no research and requires editing.